# pyInstaller execution failure due to missing Module

Tags: python, pyinstaller, sklearn-pandas

I'm not quite sure why I am finding this issue. I have installed sklearn in my environment and imported it within the code. Specifically, I am using sklearn.metrics.r2_score and I actually don't call any other sklearn modules. I am creating my one file using the following prompt input:

pyinstaller --noconsole --onefile ui_center.py advanced_plots.py find_centroid.py

I don't imagine the issue is with this... I have updated python as I've seen on a previous issue with missing sklearn modules to no effect. Would anyone have any clues? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

edit: uninstalled sklearn and reinstalled, no effect

Comment: https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/when-things-go-wrong.html#listing-hidden-imports

Try the methods listed on the pyinstaller docs

Comment: Are you using a venv? If you are make sure you have activated it before creating exe

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63301741/how-to-resolve-pyinstaller-module-not-found-error
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25733467/no-module-named-when-using-pyinstaller
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15114695/imported-module-not-found-in-pyinstaller
There are some very good answers on these posts, hopefully they can help